# Gradle exists with non-zero value

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm working on an Adnroid app that was imported. The imported app used an old version of Gradle so I'm trying to sync it to the new ones (it used Gradle 19 I think). I'm unable to use Gradle 24 b/c there are symbol class finders that can't be found, so I'm just trying to get this working with 21, but it still won't work. Can anyone help?

Here is my outer .build file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
//        maven { url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public' }
//        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
}
```

Here is my inner .build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
//    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:21.0.0"
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
}
```

When I run this on an physical android I get this error:

```
Executing tasks: [:leafsnap:clean, :leafsnap:generateDebugSources, :leafsnap:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :leafsnap:mockableAndroidJar, :leafsnap:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :leafsnap:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-24' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\Butters Stotch\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-24-1' (Expected 'C:\Users\Butters Stotch\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-24')
Already observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-24' in 'C:\Users\Butters Stotch\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-24'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Users\Butters Stotch\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-24-1'
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:leafsnap:clean
:leafsnap:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:leafsnap:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:leafsnap:checkDebugManifest
:leafsnap:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:leafsnap:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72100Library
:leafsnap:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42100Library
:leafsnap:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6171Library
:leafsnap:prepareSeEmilsjolanderStickylistheaders252Library
:leafsnap:prepareDebugDependencies
:leafsnap:compileDebugAidl
:leafsnap:compileDebugRenderscript
:leafsnap:generateDebugBuildConfig
:leafsnap:mergeDebugShaders
:leafsnap:compileDebugShaders
:leafsnap:generateDebugAssets
:leafsnap:mergeDebugAssets
:leafsnap:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:leafsnap:generateDebugResources
:leafsnap:mergeDebugResources
:leafsnap:processDebugManifest
:leafsnap:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':leafsnap:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Butters Stotch\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741819

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    }
```

You're using gradle plugin 2.1.3 which according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) needs the following as must have dependencies.

> Android Plugin for Gradle, Revision 2.1.3 (August 2016)
>
> Dependencies:
>
> ```
>     Gradle 2.14.1 or higher.
>     Build Tools 23.0.2 or higher.
>
> This update adds compatibility with Gradle 2.14.1, which includes performance improvements, new features, and an important security fix.
> ```
>
> For more details, see the Gradle release notes.

whereas your build tool version currently set as `buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"`.
Change the build tool version to 23.0.2, update the support and appcompat dependencies accordingly and sync again.